# Binding multiple star rating in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this array

```
 "rating": [
            {
                "sno": 1,
                "question": 13,
            },
            {
                "sno": 2,
                "question": 5,
            },
            {
                "sno": 3,
                "question": 7,
            },
  ..
  .
```

from which i will create a dynamic star rating

> https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/rating?tab=overview#rating-basic

for single star i can create but i want multiple star and if i submit a form

then response of form should be like this format

```
{
    "answer": {
        "5": 4,
        "7": 3,
        "13": 4
    },
    "comments": "user comments"
}
```

Any solution Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps/concepts to create a dynamic form control by key:

1. Create a `FormGroup` for `answer` control.
2. Iterate the `rating` array and add the `FormControl` (with `question` as key) to `answer` `FormGroup`.
3. With `*ngFor` and `keyvalue` pipe to generate the nested form control(s) for  `answer` `FormGroup`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    answer: this.fb.group({}),
    comments: this.fb.control(''),
  });

  for (let rate of this.rate.rating) {
    this.answer.addControl(rate.question.toString(), new FormControl());
  }
}

get answer(): FormGroup {
  return this.form.controls.answer as FormGroup;
}

answerControl(formControl: AbstractControl<any, any>): FormControl {
  return formControl as FormControl;
}
```

```
<div formGroupName="answer">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let control of answer.controls | keyvalue">
    <label>Question {{ control.key }}</label>
    <rating [max]="5" [formControl]="answerControl(control.value)"></rating>
    <br />
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pbykn7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)